# Resumable Download in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, download

What is the best approach to write code for resumable downloads in cocoa? Should I use NSURLConnection, NSURLDownload or is there a better approach?
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) library. Unfortunately the developer does not work on this library any more, but I find it still working reliably. There is a lot of nice stuff in this lib and you can make downloads resumable with one line of code.